# How to mount powerboards with strange holes?

Tags: electrical, cables

Wondering how to mount these powerboards, with this illogical mount hole design.

[image: Mount holes facing different directions. Three boards.]

As seen in the picture, each of the keyholes are facing in a different directions. This makes mounting extremely tedious, and almost impossible to get straight. You can’t treat it like a regular powerboard with the keyholes facing the same way, where you just put the screws in the wall, put the powerboard on the wall, and then slot it in place. You can’t ‘slot’ it normally because you need to slot it in two different directions at once.

For some reason, Australia seems to love this design, with most of my powerboards having this!

Any idea why manufacturers go with this design, over having the keyholes face the same way? Any idea how to efficiently attach them?

Answer (score 3):

Orienting the keyways in different directions makes it less likely that an accidental nudge in any direction will disengage all the keyways at once.

The best way to find the proper screw locations for devices like these, and indeed for any keyway mounted devices, is to place a short screw in each keyway, pushed all the way into the narrow end of the slot, and then press or tap the device against the wall in the desired location. The sharp screw points will mark the wall, indicating the proper position for the pilot holes and mounting screws.

Comment: Alternate way to template for the keyways: take a normal piece of paper, align one of the edges with the edge of the powerbar, then simply use your thumb to create a rubbing of where the indents are. Maybe even poke a hole with a pencil. Then carry that paper to the wall, level/plumb it, and make a little dent where the screw should go. (I'm partial to spring-loaded punches.)

Comment: @Aloysius: This is a good idea. However -- while I usually have a handful of screws, nails, and other junk rattling about in my toolbox, I can *never* find a piece of paper when I need one.

Comment: I use the screw method all the time it works, some devices come with templates but not usually cheap powerstrips.+

Answer (score 1):

The hole that slots towed the other, you put that one on the screw *first*.  Then you slide the strip over into the final position.  Then you line up the other screw hole, and notch it in also.  Then you put on a wedge of wood or angle iron to keep the power strip from coming off the second screw.  It cannot come off the first screw.

Remember to drill the holes where the screw's final position is, not where the round openings are.

Answer (score 0):

Having two mounting holes 90-degrees different from each other lets you mount the same device horizontally or vertically without the manufacturer having to shoulder the huge cost of providing additional holes.

That may seem kind of stupid, but with a $10 power strip, every penny counts. Which is absolutely crazy, but that's the state of mass-market consumer products. But I digress.